# How can i add metadata on solana nft using javascript?

Tags: metaplex, metadata

I want to add metadata on solana nft.

```
export const createToken = async () => {
  let bs58 = require("bs58");
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");
  const bs = bs58.decode(secretKey);
  const wallet = Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs); // get wallet keypair
  // TokenAccount
  const mint = await createMint(
    connection,
    wallet,
    wallet.publicKey,
    null,
    0, // if value is 0, means non-fungible token
    undefined,
    {},
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  );
  console.log(mint.toBase58());
  // TokenMintAccount
  const associatedTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
    connection,
    wallet,
    mint,
    wallet.publicKey,
  );

  await mintTo(connection, wallet, mint, associatedTokenAccount.address, wallet, 1);

  let transaction = new Transaction().add(
    createSetAuthorityInstruction(mint, wallet.publicKey, AuthorityType.MintTokens, null),
  );

  const trans = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [wallet]);
  connectWithMetaplex(wallet, mint.toBase58());
};

export const connectWithMetaplex = async (wallet, tokenMintAccount) => {
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");
  // const metaplex = Metaplex.make(connection).use(keypairIdentity(wallet)).use(bundlrStorage());
  const mx = Metaplex.make(connection);

  await mx.nfts().findByMint(new PublicKey(tokenMintAccount));
  await mx.nfts().uploadMetadata({
    name: "JERRY NFT",
    description: "JERRY'S NFT 1",
  });
};
```

I refer https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js#uploadMetadata

I think there is no connection between metadata and my token address.

is there anyway make them connected?

---

```
export const createToken = async () => {
  let bs58 = require("bs58");
  const bs = bs58.decode(secretKey);
  const wallet = Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs); // get wallet keypair

  connectWithMetaplex(wallet);
};

export const connectWithMetaplex = async wallet => {
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");
  const metaplex = Metaplex.make(connection).use(keypairIdentity(wallet));

  const { uri } = await metaplex
    .nfts()
    .uploadMetadata({
      name: "JERRY NFT",
      description: "JERRYS FIRST NFT",
    })
    .run();

  const { nft } = await metaplex
    .nfts()
    .create({
      uri: uri,
      name: "JERRY NFT",
      sellerFeeBasisPoints: 100,
    })
    .run();

  console.log(nft);
};
```

update code

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using the metaplex js sdk already:

You should replace your whole createToken function with the create function from the sdk: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js#create

First run the upload, then create. It will automatically mint the token with the required accounts and add metadata to it.

Comment: thx ! you mean I delete createMint function from '@solana/spl-token' ? and I replaced it create function from '@metaplex-foundation/js' ?

Comment: Delete the first 34 lines of your snippet. Use create from @metaplex-foundation/js instead, yes.

Comment: I tried what you say. it causes 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toBuffer')'. I update my code

Comment: The error occured when I call uploadMetadata function